# Utilise button-onClick event instead of input-onChange event to change state in React

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I am currently experimenting with React and I am trying to change the background colour of a div according to what the user enters. I have created an Input-component with the input-element with a button, apart from the App-component, however I am unable to type in the input-element without the onChange-event, which I expected. I am unsure of how to change the state, of the state variable ('color' in App.js) with a button click instead of the onChange-event.

My App.js

```
const AppDiv = styled.div 
`margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
width: 100%;
`

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    color: ' ',
    name: null
  }

  colorchange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      color: event.target.value
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <AppDiv>
        <Input
        name = {this.state.name}
        colour = {this.state.color}
        colourChange = {this.colorchange}
        Changecolour = {this.changecolour}
        /> 
      </AppDiv>
    )
  }
}
```

Input.js

```
const ColorButton = styled.button
` 
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 24px/50%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
`

const ColorDiv = styled.div
`
height: 100vh;
flex-basis: 300px;
background-color: ${props => props.colour};   //Changing background with 'colour' prop 
`

const input = (props) => {

    return (
        <ColorDiv>
            <h2>What is your name</h2>
            <input type = "text" value = {props.name}/>
            <h2>Choose your colour</h2>
            <input type = "text" value = {props.colour} />
            <ColorButton onClick = {props.colourChange}> Change Colour </ColorButton>
        </ColorDiv>
    )
}
```

I am using styled-components to apply styling. Any suggestions or help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you are doing is to have 2 pieces of state. One for the text you have inputted in the `<input />` and one for the color you want the background to be.

In the App

```
 state = {
    colorText: null,
    backgroundColor: null,
  }

onTextChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      colorText: event.target.value
    })
}

onUpdateBackgroundColor = () => {
   this.setState({
     backgroundColor: this.state.colorText
   })
}

.......
 <Input
        colour = {this.state.colorText}
        backgroundColor={this.state.backgroundColor}
        onTextChange = {this.onTextChange}
        updateBackgroundColor = {this.onUpdateBackgroundColor}
  />
```

then in Input.tsx

```
background-color: ${props => props.backgroundColor};
```

```
<input type="text" value={props.colour} onChange={props.onTextChange} />
<ColorButton onClick={props.updateBackgroundColor}> Change Colour </ColorButton>
```

Note: To make this better, you should move the state into Input as keeping state in a parent component and updating it on every input change will cause a lot of renders

Answer (score 0):

You can either user a ref for you input and not having it controlled

```
export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("");
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Your Color: {color}</h1>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setColor(inputRef.current.value);
        }}
      >
        Update Color
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or having separated state for your input:

```
export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("");
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Your Color: {color}</h1>
      <input
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
          setInputValue(value);
        }}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setColor(inputValue);
        }}
      >
        Update Color
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```